# Why won't Heroku let me upgrade to a database plan above Basic?

Tags: heroku, database, postgres

Despite having recently upgraded to Professional dynos on Heroku, I still only seem to have the option to upgrade my Mini postgres DB to Basic -- no other choices. I've been searching around to try to figure out why that is, but to no avail. Can anyone advise on what I need to do to get access to "Standard 0" or the other plans described [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql)?

[image: Screenshot]